# Is there a way to 'alter' beans.xml without redeploying a WAR?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi, war

I'm packaging a WAR with multiple implementations of an interface. I have one implementation with no qualifier (i.e. @Default) and one with @Alternative. I'd like to know if there is an easy way (without editing the WAR itself) to change beans.xml to point to the alternative implementation, without having to package/deliver two different WAR files. If it's of any interest, I'm using JBoss EAP 6.4.

If not, what would be the best approach? I guess I could provide a property file where they can choose an implementation. I can then use `@Inject @Any Instance<Intf>` and match the correct implementation during server startup.

Edit:
The end goal is to be able to use the alternative implementation, even though it's not explicitly added in beans.xml alternatives.

The reason for this requirement is that the same service might be interfacing with different versions of the external system. I want to deliver the default, latest adapter implementation by default. At the same time, customers should be able to fallback to an older implementation if needed.

Comment: So you basically want to be able to decide **at boot time** whether some alternative should be enabled or not? If so, that could be doable and I would be looking at extensions. However manipulating `beans.xml` dynamically won't be an option. From CDI PoV you need to have all the data at container boot time.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv002.htm . Or describe exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @rangalo see edit

Comment: For this your best bet would be to use Instance<Intf>. See here  http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/building_plug_in_with_java